# Logging into lang-8.com with Tor Browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, javascript, website

I am trying to use the website [Lang-8](http://lang-8.com/) (a social networking site for language learning) with tor browser. I can create an account but I cannot log in. Whenever I enter my user name and password, I am redirected back to the welcome page of the site and I do not appear to be logged in.

I do not get any kind of error message, so I don't think that the site is deliberately blocking tor.

I thought that maybe https-everywhere is to blame, but I still cannot log in even if I disable it.

I have tried both Tor Browser version 3.6.6 and 4.0-alpha-3 but I cannot log in to lang-8 with either.

Has anybody had any success using lang-8 with Tor Browser?

### Update:

It seems that NoScript is causing the problem. If I disable the NoScript extension in Tor Browser (via the Addons menu item in Firefox), I can log in to lang-8. Of course, turning off NoScript is not a viable long-term solution. I tried turning on NoScript again, but adding a regexp matching lang-8 urls to the NoScript XSS protection whitelist, but this didn't help.

I have filed a [bug report](https://bugs.torproject.org/13332) on trac.torproject.org related to this issue.

Comment: Currently you are using two profiles. You can try to regain access to the first profile: https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery and/or you can ask the administrators to merge the two profiles.

Comment: I tried to merge the accounts but I don't know if it worked.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with Tor Browser. I tested it with Tor Browser and another Firefox (with and without HTTPS Everywhere). Only with Tor Browser it didn't work. Someone has to investigate a bit deeper on why this is the case. For progress you might also want to look here: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13332

Comment: Yes, I filed the bug report. As I mentioned there, and in an as-yet unapproved edit to this question, the problem seems to be caused by NoScript, not https-everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

All details can be found in the bug report [#13332](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13332).

The problems comes from the Secure Cookie Management of [NoScript](http://noscript.net/). The default installation leaves this to false, while Tor Browser sets it to true. This way not all cookie go along their way and the user can't login.

The [NoScript FAQ](http://noscript.net/faq#qa6_5) recommends to either disable Secure Cookie Managment for this site or to investigate further and send the authors of NoScript a report.

Comment: The problem is that if I disable Secure Cookie Managment for one site, it changes the request profile of my Tor Browser instance and makes me fingerprintable. (For example a malicious exit node could inject references to resources hosted at websites known to be broken by the secure cookies feature and detect ones I use, based on which ones I send cookies to). A better solution would be for Tor Browser to disable the Secure Cookies feature, or make it whitelist based (so that it is only enabled for a list of sites where it is known to work, this list being distributed with Tor Browser).